# Is it legally to clone HDD for deployment of massive OEM Windows XP PC?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, clone

Currently I have a small project that need to reinstall multiple old PCs.

I found that the the installation process of Windows is a bit slow. The old PCs use HDD and I have to use CD/DVD method to install. To reduce the time, I am considering to clone the HDD with Windows and Application installed, then change the license for each PC referring to their own license.

My step are

1. Use Clonezilla Lite Server to copy one of the reinstalled PC (product key not activated) as image
2. Restore the image to other HDDs
3. Deploy the HDDs to the old PCs
4. Boot the old PC and change the Windows License and Office License
5. Activate the product

I want to know if I can do this legally or is there any method to deploy massive Windows PC via non-network method?

Thank you.

Comment: Me and a former coworker used the Windows Deployment Service (WDS) in the past to install 12+ Laptops with the same settings and Profiles for evening courses. I don't remember how everything worked but you need to use PXE boot to create a first image and then use it to deploy to other devices. That could be something to look into.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-deployment-scenarios-and-tools

Comment: I don't have Windows Server 2003...That's why I want to avoid WDS method.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need the version 2003 or an activated server to use it. It does however work on newer versions. At least Windows Server 2012 and 2016 (R2). You could give it a try and if it requires a license you have at least tried.

Comment: Another option would be to use clonezilla.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I put the HDD in the PC and change the license for each PC
> referring to their license.

If it works and the proper license is installed, then it is legal.  Remember that you cannot move OEM licenses.  You need full Retail licensing to move installations between computers.

These must be very old and slow computers if still running XP. So you might have issues on some of them running Windows 10 as well.

Then, moving the drive to another computer can cause driver problems on the computer you are moving to.

If your licensing is good, it is legal.

But it looks like you could have many problems. Running XP and Windows 10 will not work on many computers.  New Windows 10 computers may not even run Windows 7.

Comment: The license is OEM license but I have all the license for each PC. The copy of Retail and OEM should be different, I am not sure if I can use Retail Copy to activate OEM key.

Comment: You can try using an OEM license on a retail copy. I am not sure that works. Sysprep has been used to do this.